# Looping through all images within multiple directories in ColdFusion

Tags: loops, coldfusion, directory, image-manipulation, coldfusion-8

I'm working on an image manipulation script to create smaller thumbnail images of the images that are already on the server.

The directory structure that I need to search through is as follows:

```
Content
    -Att1
        -image1
            -imgA1_1.png
            -imgA1_1_large.png
        -image2
            -imgA1_2.png
            -imgA2_large.png
        -image3
            -imgA1_3.png
            -imgA1_3_large.png
    -Att2
        -image1
            -imgA2_1.png
            -imgA2_1_large.png
        -image2
            -imgA2_2.png
            -imgA2_2_large.png
        -image3
            -imgA2_3.png
            -imgA2_3_large.png
    -Att3
        -image1
            -imgA3_1.png
            -imgA3_1_large.png
        -image2
            -imgA3_2.png
            -imgA3_2_large.png
        -image3
            -imgA3_3.png
            -imgA3_3_large.png

etc...
```

So what I would like to to is be able to loop through all of the images shown above and if the dimensions of that image exceed 500-500 then create a thumbnail that is 100-100.

Is there any way of doing this without looping through each directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cfdirectory` has a recurse attribute. This will loop through all the folders, but it won't require you to write code to loop through all the folders

```
<cfdirectory directory="yourDirectory" recurse="yes">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with very large directories cfdirecotry ends up being very slow.  Here is a function that uses java that I wrote since we have some directories that have 1000s of images. It looks through and creates a query result for all your files and is MUCH faster

```
<cffunction name="getDirectorylisting" returntype="query" output="true">
        <cfargument name="dirName" type="string" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="recurse" type="boolean" default="false" required="false" />
        <cfargument name="dirInfo1" type="query" default="#queryNew('datelastmodified,name,size,type,directory,hidden,pathname')#">
            <cfscript>
                var thisFile = '';
                var listFiles = '';
                var pathToParse = trim(dirName);

                var thisPath = '';
                var relPath = '';
                var theFileObj = '';
                var isDir = '';
                var isFile = '';
                var thisSize = '';
                var lastModified = '';
                var isHidden = '';
                var theType = '';

                if (left(dirName,2) == 'c:' || left(dirName,2) == 'd:' || left(dirName,2) == 'e:' || left(dirName,2) == '\\'){
                    //do nothing path is already absolute
                } else {
                    pathToParse = expandPath(pathToparse);
                }
                if(right(pathToParse,1) == '/' || right(pathToParse,1) == '\'){pathToParse = left(pathToParse,len(pathToParse)-1);}
                if(right(dirName,1) == '/' || right(dirName,1) == '\'){dirName = left(dirName,len(dirName)-1);}
                if (directoryExists(pathToParse)){
                    listFiles =  createObject("java","java.io.File").init(pathToParse).list();
                    for (thisFile=1;thisFile<=arrayLen(listFiles);thisFile=thisFile+1){
                        queryAddRow(arguments.dirInfo1);
                        thispath = "#pathToParse#\#listFiles[thisFile]#";
                        relpath = "#dirName#/#listFiles[thisFile]#";
                        theFileObj = createObject("java","java.io.File").init(thispath);
                        isDir = theFileObj.isDirectory();
                        isFile = theFileObj.isFile();
                        thisSize = val(theFileObj.length());
                        lastModified = theFileObj.lastModified();
                        isHidden = theFileObj.isHidden();
                        theType = "dir";
                        if (isFile){theType = "file";}
                        querySetCell(arguments.dirInfo1,"datelastmodified", lastModified );
                        querySetCell(arguments.dirInfo1,"name", listFiles[thisFile] );
                        querySetCell(arguments.dirInfo1,"size", thisSize );
                        querySetCell(arguments.dirInfo1,"directory", pathToParse );
                        querySetCell(arguments.dirInfo1,"hidden", isHidden );
                        querySetCell(arguments.dirInfo1,"type", theType );
                        querySetCell(arguments.dirInfo1,"pathName", relPath );
                        if (arguments.recurse && isDir && !isHidden){
                            arguments.dirInfo1 = getDirectoryListing(relPath,true, arguments.dirInfo1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return arguments.dirInfo1;
            </cfscript>
    </cffunction>
```